# Show deleted notification on direct URL

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, information-display

Please show a deleted notification when browsing to the direct URL of a deleted question.  I find it vary annoying when I'm watching a question (pressing F5 every hour or so), and it simply disappears.  I know that it was there, but now I'm treated to a page not found error like I typed something random into the browser.  I'd don't need the explanation as to why it was deleted, although that would be nice.

Answer (score -3):

Well, if you view the 404 page..

https://stackoverflow.com/404

You'll note that it already says

> Occasionally questions or answers may be removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etcetera.

almost all the time, the post was deleted by the author, by the way... it's very rare for it to be editorial or spam.

Comment: I realize that the scenario is mentioned.  That's why I'm assuming that the question was deleted.  It's misleading, and I normally come to SO for clarity.

Comment: Still, there is no way to tell whether one got the URL wrong, or a question used to be there and was deleted. It would be nice to have some distinction